# Improving Intersection Algorithm

Tags: java, intersection, sortedlist

I have a algorithm to build the intersection of two sorted lists. If I compare it with java.util.BitSet in a performance test, my algorithm is slow.

```java
    public static List<Integer> intersection(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
            int size1 = list1.size(), size2 = list2.size();
            int capacity = size1 < size2 ? size1 : size2;
            List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(capacity);
            int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
            while (i1 < size1 && i2 < size2) {
                if (list1.get(i1) < list2.get(i2))
                    i1++;
                else if (list2.get(i2) < list1.get(i1))
                    i2++;
                else {
                    intersection.add(list2.get(i2++));
                    i1++;
                }
            }
            return intersection;
        }
```

Anyone sees any improvement?

Thanks

Comment: Use `BitSet`, or even `int[]`. Specifying a capacity for the `ArrayList` is probably a mistake. Probably doesn't need to be that large. Also you only need two `get`s per loop. Even that can be reduced if you only `get` on an associated increment. You may want to consider using `Iterator`s, particularly if you are given a `LinkedList` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Are the inputs to your function always of type `ArrayList`?

- If they are, algorithmically there is nothing wrong with your method. I'd make two changes:

  1. I'd change the argument types to `ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2`;
  2. I'd only call `list1.get(i1)` and `list2.get(i2)` once. This may or may not make any difference to performance, but stylistically I prefer to factor this out.
- If you need to support any list, then I'd rewrite the function in terms of two iterators, since calling `get(index)` could be very expensive.

Finally, when testing performance, make sure to follow the advice given in [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should know that this:

```
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(capacity);
```

allocates an internal array of size `capacity`.

Suppose `list1.size() == 5000`, and `list2.size() == 5000`, and `intersection(list1, list2).size() == 3`, the method would allocate 4997 useless integers.

Try using a reasonable capacity (depending on the use of the method) or just leave it to the default value (which is 10).

(Bare in mind that the complexity of allocating an array of size `n` (or an `ArrayList` of *capacity* `n`) is **`O(n)`**.)

Comment: Isn't it expensive to allocate more space in an ArrayList?

Comment: It is expensive to allocate more space, it is also expensive to let the `ArrayList` resize its internal array too many time, you should choose a reasonable `capacity`